# How do I show count of all participants and count of participants that meet a criteria (searchkit)

Tags: searchkit

I'm trying to build a table that shows something like this:

> EventTitle | EventStart | Total Participants | Count of Participants
> with CustomField=Y

Using searchkit, I can get this easily:

> EventTitle | EventStart | Total Participants

and I can also get this easily:

> EventTitle | EventStart | Count of Participants with CustomField=Y

But I can't seem to think of a way to both filter on participants who have that custom field but also list all participants.  In the filter tab it seems like I can either filter on these users or not.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be doable with 2 joins.

- **Search for:** Events
- **With (optional):** Participants
- **With (optional):** Contacts IF custom field = x

Counting the first join should give you all participants, and counting the second should give you just the ones with the custom field.

Comment: Thank you!  I had never used the "Contacts IF field = x" construct on the "Search For" tab before.  I don't think I've even seen that you could filter on that tab before.  So thank you!  This totally worked!